# How to use advanced filter to filter entire data set, but copy only a single column?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to learn how to use advanced filter to filter an entire data set, based on one or two values, and then copy a single column (filtered) to a new worksheet. Preferably, I'd want to copy only the unique values. I am able to copy the entire data set or a subset of columns then delete my excess columns, remove duplicates, etc. but I know there must be a better and faster way.

Below is the code I have currently - which works, but is a bit slow:

```
wk.Range("BL2").Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value 'assign filter values
    sh.Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Name = "Data"
    sh.Range("Data").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wk.Range("Filter"), copytorange:=wh.Range("A1:CT1")
    lr = wh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wh.Range("A1:AR" & lr).ClearContents 'remove unnecessary data
    wh.Range("AT1:CT" & lr).ClearContents 'remove unnecessary data
    wh.Range("AS1:AS" & lr).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
    lr = wh.Range("AS" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'reset last row
    Set oneRange = wh.Range("AS1:AS" & lr)
    Set aCell = wh.Range("AS1")
    oneRange.Sort key1:=aCell, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    With ws
        myArray = wh.Range("AS2:AS" & lr + 1)
        ws.Activate
        ComboBox3.List = myArray
    End With
```

Comment: You want to do multiple things and it is better to break them down to separate routines or functions, for example, making a list of values unique should be a separate function. Also, if you give us what type of filtration you want to apply we can come up with the code.

Comment: My main problem is understanding how to just copy a single column from the filtered data set. I tried Filterinplace and then copied only visible cells, but this was slow

Comment: Have you tried autofilter?

Comment: No, my assumption was Advanced Filter was faster

Comment: If you have too manty rows, it will be slow with any method, to copy the visible cells faster you may use `copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")`  where tgt is your target sheet

Comment: Regarding code's speed, try toggling Application.Calculation to False immediately before you filter, then to True after you've copied the visible cells. I was under the impression that Advanced Filter can filter through millions of cells in seconds and can return uniques only (meaning you wouldn't need to call `RemoveDuplicates` after).

Comment: I have calculation turned off

Comment: I think your first three lines can be reduced to `sh.currentregion.name = "Data"`. You could also reduce two lines where you've commented 'remove unnecessary data' to `wh.Range("A1:AR" & LR & ",AT1:AS" & LR).clearcontents`.

Also, try passing `Unique:=True` when you use `AdvancedFilter`, see if it achieves the same result as `RemoveDuplicates`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try/use the those updates